# assembly mips use the function blt

Tags: assembly, mips, registration, mips32, select-syscall

where is my mistake? I need to print all the number that are bigger than zero and divided by 4.

it says:

> (1).zip line 32: Runtime exception at 0x0040000c: address out of range 0x00000000

thanks a alot

```
num1: .word -8 , num3
num2: .word 1998 , 0
num3: .word -9034 , num5
num4: .word -100 , num2
num5: .word 1972, num4

###############################code segment ###########################################################
.text 
.globl main

main: #main program entry #load num1 from memory to $t0 (pesudo- instr)


secod: 
                  la $t0,num1   
                  li $a0,0 
                  
        
Secondloop: 
  
                 lw $t1, 0($t0)
                 blt $t1 , $zero , notCount
                   lw $t0, 4($t0)
                   andi $t2 , $t1 , 3
                    beq $t2, $zero, theSecondCheck
                    
                    j Secondloop
                 
             
notCount:     
                    lw $t0, 4($t0) 
                   beq $t0,$zero,secondPrint  
                    j Secondloop
 theSecondCheck:  
                           
                  beq $t2,$zero,sum 
                  j Secondloop
                 
   sum: 
                  add $a0, $t1, $a0
                  j Secondloop
 secondPrint: #print the result 
        
    li $v0,1
    syscall      
  
  
thirdLoop: 
                la $t0,num1
                lw $t1, 0($t0) 
             lw $t0, 4($t0)
            beq $t0,$zero,continuePrint
                li $v0,11
                bge $t1,$zero,printFourBase
                li $a0, '-'
                syscall
                sub $t1,$zero,$t1
printFourBase:
                li $t3,16
                li $v0,1 
continuePrint:
                rol $t1,$t1,2
                andi $a0,$t1,3
                syscall
                addi $t3,$t3,-1
                bne $t3,$zero,Exit
                j continuePrint


Exit: 
    li $v0,10
```

Comment: step through a debugger until you hit something unexpected. you can ask a better more specific question then

Comment: That error is within 3 instruction addresses of the start location, so should be really easy for you to debug, What instruction is at 400..0c??

Comment: Looks like you forgot to check `$t0` for being a NULL pointer at the end of your linked list, along one path of execution.  You're comparing some other register.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code I have made in the past:

```
.data 

result: .space 4
num1: .word -8,num3
num2: .word 1988,0 
num3: .word -9034,num5 
num4: .word -100, num2
num5: .word 1972, num4 

.text

main:

    li   $a0, 128  #numbers of bytes to allocated
    li   $v0, 9    #sys function allocate heap memory
    syscall
    
    la $t1, result
    sw $v0, ($t1)  #store the address of the allocated heap memory in result

    la $t0, num1

while:
    lw $a0, ($t0)

print_value:
  
        lw $a0, ($t0)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    lw $a0, ($t0)
    jal base10to4
    
    li $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall


    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    
    lw $t0, ($t0)
        
    beq $t0, 0, end_while 
    
    j while
    
end_while:

end_program:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

base10to4:


    move $s0,$a0
    la   $s7,result 


    li $a0, '|'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    li   $s1, 4
    li   $s2, 0 #index for the result array
    li   $s6, 0 #will keep track if number is negative of positive 
    
divide_loop:
    
    beq  $s0, $zero, end_loop
    
    div  $s0, $s0, $s1
    mfhi $s5
    
    
    move $s3, $s2 
    mul  $s3, $s3, $s1
    lw   $s4, ($s7)
    add  $s3, $s3, $s4
    blt  $s5, $zero, negative
    j    next

negative:
    li   $s6, 1 
    mul  $s5, $s5, -1 # if negative then make positive

next:
    sw   $s5, ($s3)

    addi $s2, $s2, 1 #increment index with 1
    j divide_loop
    
end_loop:   

print_result:
        # $s2 will contain the range of result array
    addi $s2, $s2, -1
    beq $s6, 1, print_minus
        j print_loop
        
print_minus:

    li   $a0, '-'
    li   $v0, 11
    syscall

                          
print_loop: 
    blt $s2, $zero end_print_loop
    
    move $s3, $s2 
    mul  $s3, $s3, 4
    lw   $s4, ($s7)
    add $s3, $s3, $s4
    lw   $s5, ($s3)

    addi $s2, $s2, -1 #increment with 4 for the next address memory location
    
    move $a0, $s5
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    
    j print_loop
    
end_print_loop:

return_base10to4:

    jr $ra
```